# Scala converting Map[String, Int]("a"->2, "b"->1) to Sequence Seq("a", "a", "b")

Tags: scala

I have for example a map such as Map("a" -> 2, "b" -> 4). I want to convert it to a Sequence such that Seq("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b").

Im currently doing this:

```
(for (e <- theMap) yield
      for (_ <- 0 until e._2) yield e._1).flatten).toSeq
```

My question is: what would be a better/more sophisticated approach to doing this because I am pretty sure the a double yield for loop is not necessary and scala allows you to it in a 'nicer' way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Range](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-range-class-in-scala-cookbook/) to repeat the character and "replace" `yield` with `map`:

```
theMap 
  .map(t => 0.until(t._2).map(_ => t._1))
  .flatten
```

Comment: Thanks, using a range to fill it, perfectly fits into 'a nicer way' and I learned something new from your post, thanks!